# Quiz permissions per user

Tags: quiz

I have installed the [quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module in drupal 7 and I know that there is a permission to allow roles participate in all quizzes. I want that a specific role can participate in specific quiz, not in all quizzes, and other roles can participate in their own quizzes.

Is there anyway to accomplish this through the interface? If not, I would like to know how to solve it by coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is a module for this: [OG Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_quiz). According to its description:

> This modules creates permissions similar to the core Quiz ones on the
>   group level. This allows site builders to give Quiz
>   creation/correction/taking permissions at the group level instead of
>   globally.